# How to prevent to run last successfully built application in Visual Studio when there are errors?

Tags: visual-studio

I accidentally pressed `Yes` instead of `No` with enabled checkbox `Don't ask again` after I pressed `F5` and there were errors.
I want to see errors after `F5` instead of running last successfully built application if there are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tools -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run

[image]